# How to inquire about Job application application status submitted four weeks without reponse

Tags: applications

I have submitted a job application for the past 4weeks and still waiting for the recruiting manager to get back to me, I want to send him an email but don't know how to go about it.

Comment: In general, if you aren't contacted for 4 weeks you are not getting an interview. Sadly, in this day and age, it's the exception rather than the rule to receive any kind of acknowledgement. In the future, if you want to confirm a recruiting manager has at least received your application, you could always contact them a day or two after you send it.

Comment: Does the job ad have a closing date? Some places won't reply to anyone until after the closing date and all candidates have been filtered for selection.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello,
>
> I have recently submitted an X  to your Y.  Can you give me an update
>   regarding Z?
>
> Thank you,
>
> Margareth.

Define the variables before you compile